# How do I join two tables in hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-webflow

How do I join two tables in hibernate and Spring. below is my suto java code and I need to do a join on objectA where the name field is equal to the name field in objectB but I am going to be searching on ObjectA ID field but I need returned. ObjectA ID, ObjectA Name, ObjectA Regin, ObjectB Address.

```
//
// CLASS OBJECT A
//
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
public class ObjectA {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id; 

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name; 

    @Column(name = "region")
    private String region; 

}

//
// CLASS OBJECT B
//
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableB")
public class ObjectB {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id; 

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name; 

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address; 

}
```

can someone please tell me how to do this within the java code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your A class:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="name")
private ObjectB objectB;
```

So that when you retrieve for A, you'll get inside corresponding B by name.

Comment: how does it know the col in ObjectA and the col in ObjectB to match on

Comment: @techsjs2012 JoinColumn indicates that the field/column to target on the other class is "name".  If you wanted a bidirectional association, in the B class on the name field, you must add the annotation: @OneToOne(mappedBy="name")  name corresponding to the A class's one

Answer (score 0):

Use a cross join with a condition in the where clause to limit the join.  This is the only good way (other than native sql) that i know of, to join two objects when there is no mapped relationship between them.

You can do this easily with an hql query

```
select a.id, a.name, a.region, b. address
from ObjectA a, ObjectB b
where a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use inner join
select A.ID,A.Name,A.Regin,B.Address
from ObjectA as A inner join  ObjectB as B